# 12 speed sram DUB chainring compatibility

Tags: crankset, chainring, compatibility, sram

Can A 12 speed DUB 1x road crankset (Force 1) be converted to 11 speed by swapping the respective chainrings?

I have an 11 speed Force 1 rear mech that I want to use for the moment, but want to use DUB cranks

Comment: Which crankset is it exactly? For MTB dranksets you can just use the same chainring  for 12x and 11x afaik, not sure about the gravel groups.

Comment: @reciprocallettuce That answer you deleted was a valid answer. You could consider reinstating it! It isn't complete, because if the OP has a road crank with AXS rings, they shouldn't use a non-AXS chain. However, 3rd party manufacturers may make SRAM direct mount 1x rings or spiders for 1x rings, e.g. Wolf Tooth appears to. Feel free to use this data to expand your answer. https://www.wolftoothcomponents.com/collections/chainrings/products/camo-aluminum-round-chainring

Comment: @reciprocallettuce, I’m thinking of the road group— I’ll update my question

Comment: @WeiwenNg thanks for the hint on third party manufacturers. I hope I didn't get anything wrong and reinstated my answer. If you have any ideas on how to improve it please comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to swap the chainring. From one of my favourite online resellers of bike parts I get the following description of a Sram NX crankset (MTB group):

[image: bc screenshot]

This means they sell the same set for 11x and 12x.

If you want to change the chainring, I suppose you would need one with a 8-Bolt Direct Mount:

[image: 8 bolt direct mount as in force 1 12x]

As suggested in the comments, third party manufacturers offer explicitely 11x compatible chainrings with Sram 8-bolt direct mount. Wolf Tooth calls this 'Drop-Stop B tooth profile'.

Answer (score 0):

Having just talked to SRAM, they told me the 12 speed crankset is backwards compatible for use with an 11 speed system.
Just make sure to use the 11 speed chain with it.

Comment: Do you have any infos that back up this theory, e.g. technical documentation from SRAM? I think the accepted answer above pretty much states the same but is based on a shop listing those cranks.

Comment: I would like to disagree about yout point of using 11 speed chain. You can use 12 speed chain with no loss of performance on 11 speed drivetrain (but not the other way around). In fact a lot of SRAM 11 speed drivetrains run smoother and quieter with 12 speed SRAM chains. I am currently running GX eagle chain on my 11 speed SRAM drivetrain happily for over 10 000 KM.

Comment: @ArtGertner you have to be careful. The standard Eagle 12x Chains are backwards compatible. But Sram Road 12x and the new AXS Transmission groups use flat top chains. These have larger rollers, thus are not backwards compatible with Eagle or 11x.

Comment: The original question is based on a 12s road crank. I'm surprised a SRAM rep said it was compatible. I think this directly contradicts their official stance.